# Spark job very slow at sort stage for iceberg insert operation with local sort

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-iceberg

I am inserting data from one iceberg table to another iceberg table with local sort defined on destination table `alter table schema1.test_iceberg_ordered1 WRITE DISTRIBUTED BY PARTITION LOCALLY ORDERED BY example_event_cd NULLS LAST` while if I do the insert on same table using global sort then it executes 10 times faster which is abnormal as local sort has less work to do.

I see spill disk and maybe I am missing something on spark side due to which getting this performance degradation.

```
spark.sql(f""" insert into Omniture_new.core_page_view_iceberg_ordered1
               select * from Omniture_new.core_page_view_iceberg where page_view_dtm between timestamp '2023-05-21 00:00:00' and timestamp '2023-05-23 23:59:59' """)
```

Spark configuration

```
                        .config('spark.master','yarn')
                        
                        .config("spark.executor.instances","20")
                        .config("spark.executor.cores",30)
                        .config("spark.executor.memory","8G")
                        
                        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",10)
                        
                        .config("spark.default.parallelism",200)
                        
                        .config("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.parallelismFirst","false")
                        .config("spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes",10737418240)
                        .config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "24182400")
                        .config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true")
                        
                        .config("spark.driver.memory","16G")
```

Below is the task execution and spark plan.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am dealing with similar issues. as you have pointed out your spilling to disk and there is a lot of data that is being shuffled.  You may want to increase your partition count?  If you have already solved this problem could you pls note your steps :-) thx.

Comment: How can I increase partition count except shuffle partition which causes more number of smaller files

Comment: That is a fair point but having smaller files may mean less spill to disk: see if this article helps - https://selectfrom.dev/spark-performance-tuning-spill-7318363e18cb